# Live server doesn't refresh the page in vscode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

The live server starts successfully in vscode but the page doesn't refresh after saving. I have also enabled auto-save and configured auto-save option in settings from "off" to "afterDelay". I have even tried shortcut key "alt + l, alt + o" to start the server and . It starts successfully but doesn't refresh the page.

Comment: can you share your server link that's open when live-server is started it should be something like this: `127.0.0.1:5000/index.html`

Comment: http://localhost:5500/index.html